# get json file from the url in android

Tags: android, json

I'm new in android and in stackoverflow.
I have the url that have this text in it.

> projects: [ {id: 2, name: 'A'}, {id: 3, name: 'Modern A'}, {id: 4, name: 'Old A'} ]

that is the text with json format. I'd like to get the json file of it and process it.

Comment: looks like you haven't done a lot of research. start here: androidhive.info/2012/01/android-json-parsing-tutorial

Comment: @ahlemjarrar, wrap your link in `[link](http://example.com)` so it be clickable, for further comment formatting read [this](http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help#comment-formatting)

Answer (score 1):

I'd suggest starts reading about Gson and Volley. Both are libraries from Google to easily consuming RESTful API Calls and formating Json into Models/POJOs. Or atleast show us what you already tried and some code.